# Unity 5 - Texture/Material rendering issue

Tags: unity, textures, shaders, materials

I am working on a Minesweeper clone that started as a Unity 4.6 project and ended up as a Unity 5 project. I have cube objects that use Legacy Shaders/Diffuse. I am new to Unity 5, so I am not fully aware of the changes to the shaders.

The following texture on cube objects does not render as it is (I think it used to).
[image]

[image]

I want the flag appear on the cube as it is. What causes this output and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the png file doesn't have any background (I expected there to be a white background behind the flag image). This is how Unity handles textures when the texture file (PNG) doesn't have a background. Get a white background in the texture file and you're good to go.